# Coffeescript / Jquery binding events best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Iam new to coffescript but i iam interested what is the best way to bind events from jquery to coffeescript class instance? Iam trying to prevent having too many nested callbacks in my class:

```
class Page
  id2clicks : 0
  id3clicks : 0
  id4clicks : 0

  onLoad: ->

    $('#id2').on 'click', @ , @onId2Click

    $('#id3').on 'click', $.proxy(@onId3Click,@)

    $('#id4').on 'click' , () =>
      @id4clicks++
      alert @id4clicks

  onId2Click: (e) ->
    e.data.id2clicks++
    alert e.data.id2clicks

  onId3Click: ->
    @id3clicks++
    alert @id3clicks

p = new Page()
p.onLoad()
```

All 3 methods works... is there any better way / recommandation to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer this way, as it is the shortest and shows the handler in-line (notice that I also omitted the parentheses):

```
$('#id4').on 'click' , =>
  @id4clicks++
  alert @id4clicks
```

This is very good for short handlers. However, occasionally you have a function that you want to split out and reuse elsewhere, in which case I prefer to use something like

```
$('#id2').on 'click', $.proxy(@onId2Click, @)
```

or even

```
$('#id2').on 'click', (e) =>
  @onId2Click e
```

Another way is to write

```
onId3Click: =>
  @id3clicks++
  alert @id3clicks
```

and use

```
$('#id3').on 'click', @onId3Click
```

But I would personally discourage this because most people don't expect `@onId3Click` to be a bound function and it forces them to jump to the part of the code where it's defined to check.

Comment: It's interesting that `onId3Click: =>` ends up applying a `__bind(this.onId3Click, this)`, where `__bind` is roughly equivalent to `$.proxy`.

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript introduced an entire piece of syntax specifically for this problem: The fat arrow, `=>`. Use it:

```
$('#id4').click (event) =>
  @id4clicks++
  alert @id4clicks
```

Comment: He knows the operator already, he is asking for best practises.

Comment: And I'm telling him: The authors of the language went through the effort of solving this problem at the *language* level. **Of course** you should use the fat arrow.

Answer (score 1):

There are 23 (and counting) revisions of the jsperf.com tests for binding methods

http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/23

other ways of doing this binding include:

```
$('#id3').on 'click', @onId3Click.bind(@)  # native bind

$('#id3').on 'click', _.bind(@onId3Click, @) # underscore, lodash
```

In general `$.proxy` and underscore are slower, native bind is fast on some browsers, slow on V8, and lodash can distinguish between the two.